# In Django admin, can I require fields in a model but not when it is inline?

Tags: django, django-admin

In django admin, there are fields I'd like to require if a model is being edited standalone. If it is inline, I don't want them to be required. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

While Daniel Roseman's answer works, it's not the best solution. It requires a bit of code duplication by having to re-declare the form field. For example, if you had a `verbose_name` on that field, you would also have to add `label='My verbose_name already set on model'` to the `CharField` line, since re-declaring the whole field basically erases everything set on your model for that field.

The better approach is to override the form's `__init__` method and explicitly set `field.required` to `True` or `False` there.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['myfield'].required = True
```

Comment: just so people know, it also works with instance of  django.contrib.auth.forms.UserChangeForm

Answer (score 12):

Sure. Just define a custom form, with your required field overridden to set required=True, and use it in your admin class.

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    required_field = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyForm


class MyInlineAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = MyModel
```

So here MyAdmin is using the overridden form, but MyInlineAdmin isn't.